# how to use timedistributed before GRU in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I build a model CNN, the input dimension is (none,100,100,1) and the output is (400*1) but when I run my model, some errors happen, and here is my model:

```
visible_image1= Input(shape=(100,100,1))
conv_1=Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same',  
             )(visible_image1)
BatchNor_1=BatchNormalization()(conv_1)
relu_1=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_1)
pool_1=(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(3,3)))(relu_1)
conv_2=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(pool_1)
BatchNor_2=BatchNormalization()(conv_2)
relu_2=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_2)
conv_3=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_2)
BatchNor_3=BatchNormalization()(conv_3) 
relu_3=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_3)  

conv_4=Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_3) 
BatchNor_4=BatchNormalization()(conv_4)  

conv_5=Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )( BatchNor_3) 
BatchNor_5=BatchNormalization()(conv_5) 
add_1=Add()([BatchNor_4,BatchNor_5])
relu_4=LeakyReLU(0.2)(add_1)  
conv_6=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_4)
BatchNor_6=BatchNormalization()(conv_6)  
relu_5=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_6) 
conv_7=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_5)  
BatchNor_7=BatchNormalization()(conv_7) 
relu_6=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_7)
conv_8=Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_6) 
BatchNor_8=BatchNormalization()(conv_8)  
add_2=Add()([BatchNor_8, relu_4])
relu_7=LeakyReLU(0.2)(add_2)
conv_9=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_7)               
BatchNor_9=BatchNormalization()(conv_9) 
relu_8=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_9)
conv_10=Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_8) 
BatchNor_10=BatchNormalization()(conv_10) 
relu_9=LeakyReLU(0.2)(BatchNor_10)
conv_11=Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
             )(relu_9)
BatchNor_11=BatchNormalization()(conv_11) 
add_3=Add()([BatchNor_11, relu_7])
relu_10=LeakyReLU(0.2)(add_3)
time_1=TimeDistributed(Dense(256))(relu_10)   #
gru_1=GRU(256, return_sequences=True)(time_1)
flatten_1 = Flatten()(gru_1)  
fc_1=Dense(3000,activation = "relu")(flatten_1)
fc_2=Dense(1000,activation = "relu")(fc_1)
fc_3=Dense(401,activation = "softmax")(fc_2)
```

The error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

As far as I know, relu_10 output dim is (none 33 33 256) and after timedistributed, the dimemsion should be 3D,because gru layer should have 3D input, my question is how can I make the dimension because 3D after timedistributed layer?

And what is the function of the timedistributed ?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? GRUs are not to be used with images unless you're experimenting very particular ideas. What do you consider a "time steps" dimension in your images?

Comment: `TimeDistributed` doesn't change the number of dimensions. It makes the "wrapped layer" ignore one dimension. In your code, "Dense" is wrapped, but "GRU" is not. GRU is seeing all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to repeat the result of the article"[enter link description here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1805/1805.00312.pdf)",but I cannot fix the problem "Timedistributed", I wonder What else layer was used in this article? GRU is just used to find the relation between the input data. I really want to know what is wrong with mu code ,because I am a new leaner about Kears,I have beeing coding for more than two weeks .